# Importing custom fonts in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, sass, fonts, laravel-mix

I'm trying to load custom fonts to my project using Laravel 8 (mix) but don't know what's wrong with my process. Whenever I'm trying to use the font with my scss the font seems not working.

Here's what my directory tree looks like atm:

**My Public Directory**

public

- assets

  - css
  - js
- css

  - app.css
- js

  - app.js

**My Resources Directory**

resources

- fonts

  - opensans.ttf
- sass

  - app.scss

Now the `app.scss` contains the following

```
$font-path: "../fonts";
@font-face {
    src: url("#{$font-path}/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("ttf");
    font-family: "OpenSans";
}
```

I even tried putting the fonts inside `public` folder but it didn't work, also I tried importing the font from google fonts it didn't work too.

Comment: Did you check your Chrome console for any errors ? You should have your fonts in `public` directory, like `public/fonts/opensans.ttf`.

Comment: There's no error in console.  I tried it also but it didn't work in loading the fonts to my `css`.

Comment: Then do this, try to find the `css` file in the `sources` tab, and then see what the final URL is. Also, see that you are using `OpenSans-Regular.ttf` when you wrote you have `opensans.ttf` in your `fonts` folder...

Comment: copy, sorry still a newbie but will try it thanks bud.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a rule copy folder with fonts in `laravel.mix.js` to `public/fonts`

```js
mix.copy('resources/fonts', 'public/fonts');
```